# How to get Atlassian Confluence Space permissions by REST API?

Tags: java, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm using Atlassian Confluence REST API. I need to get Space permissions. I couldn't find any info on it in the documentation.

Does anyone know how to get these permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see virtually no documentation about this, however having looked at the Confluence REST API Browser, I've got a working example below. You have to be a Confluence admin, or space admin for the space...

**POST:** `http://localhost:1990/confluence/rpc/json-rpc/confluenceservice-v2/getSpacePermissionSets`

**BODY:** `[ "ds" ]`

**RESPONSE:**

```
[
  {
    "type": "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "SETPAGEPERMISSIONS",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEMAIL",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "EXPORTPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "CREATEATTACHMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "VIEWSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "VIEWSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EDITBLOG",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITBLOG",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVEPAGE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "REMOVECOMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "EDITSPACE",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "EDITSPACE",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "COMMENT",
    "spacePermissions": [
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-users"
      },
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": "confluence-administrators"
      },
      {
        "type": "COMMENT",
        "userName": null,
        "groupName": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's using the old JSON-RPC REST APIs which have been deprecated and will eventually be replaced. But when they are replaced, you can refactor, right?

Comment: Hello from 2022 - it seems like this API has indeed been deprecated but without any alternative. The new solution that I've seen online is to write your own Java plugin for the server to give you access to space-level permissions