# Work with Confluence Space Permissions via REST API 5.5+

Tags: rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

How can I get / add / remove Space permission via REST API for Confluence 5.5 + ?

I didn't find nothing about permission in official docs: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/

Answer (score 0):

From this [link on atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/328398/confluence-set-permission-to-space-programmatically), it seems like REST permission management is not possible.

But you can use the [Java ContentPermissionManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/core/ContentPermissionManager.html) or the [legacy RPC methods](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-xml-rpc-and-soap-apis/remote-confluence-methods#RemoteConfluenceMethods-Permissions.1) (yuck!) to do this

Answer (score 0):

See if you have access to the REST API Browser, you should be able to search/browse the available APIs and available functions

[Using the Rest API Browser](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/developer-tools/using-the-rest-api-browser)

If there are permissions functions that are "undocumented" I imagine you'll find them there

Comment: I just found this as well, I think it directly addresses what you are asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128721/how-to-get-atlassian-confluence-space-permissions-by-rest-api/27226400#27226400